# Internet latency map

Tags: internet, latency

I would like to see a latency map, showing the lowest latencies achieved between various destinations around the world. What is for example the lowest latencies achieved between Denmark and India. This could for example be used for planning of where to place a server farm for online games.

Comment: https://www.dotcom-tools.com/internet-backbone-latency.aspx which shows point-to-point worldwide latency measurements. The Copenhagen to Mumbai delays are the closest cities for your example.

Comment: You can select ping times between many cities around the world using [this](https://wondernetwork.com/pings). Click on `Update Pings` button and delete the default cities, then select the cities you are interested in, then scroll down to see ping times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this old question as it’s a popular Google search result. I’ve found https://wondernetwork.com/pings to be very useful. It also covers many more cities than e.g. comparing latencies between AWS regions.

Answer (score 5):

Consider Keynote's

> [Internet Health Report](http://www.internetpulse.net/)
>   http://www.internetpulse.net/

or

> [The Internet Weather Map (IWM](http://www.internetweathermap.com/))
>   http://www.internetweathermap.com/

for a starting point.

Though I confess that I don't entirely understand your question.  Surely you need to first understand where your customers are.  For example, if your game becomes popular in Brazil ([fifth most populous country in the world](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2119rank.html)), you're really going to want to put a server closer to Brazil, regardless of whether you have a co-lo with good latency characteristics between Denmark and India :)

Comment: Maybe the best place to serve the brazilian market would be from Surinam? Opera, which has HUGE networking needs have just placed many of their servers on Iceland. Who could guess. I do believe that latency is not the big issue for them, but Iceland actually has really good bandwidth.

Comment: The second link seemed relevant, but I was unable to figure out the latency between denmark and india.

Comment: the internet is changing...will cloud, remote services ,ajax , remote api's it's really about latency not 'speed'. The two are related, but if need high interactivity with a small payload then latency is king! You'll always have the speed of light as a barrier!! Choose isp's that are wirespeed!! and more importantly can offer you a latency SLA!!!!!! (if you can find one!)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.akamai.com/html/technology/dataviz1.html
An internet weather map, yes the internet has its own weather.

This site seams to give pretty good info about the whole internet.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work right now.